# Resizing a rectangle drawn in drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I have two `UIViews`. My aim is to draw the smallest rectangle which contains both these `UIView`s. I thought to draw a rectangle using the frame which I'll get out of

`CGRectUnion(view1.frame, view2.frame);`

But when I move any of the two `UIView`s, I need to update the frame of the outlining rectangle.

I thought I could do this by :

1) Resizing the previously drawn rectangle.

(or)

2) Deleting the previously drawn rectangle and drawing a new one.

The problem is that, I don't know how to get the instance of the previously drawn rectangle. So, I don't know how to update or delete it..

Can any of you guys help?
Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: You could try keeping a reference to whatever rectangles you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can declare the following in your .h file:

```
CGRect *transformingRect;
```

Doing so should retain the rectangle and its properties so long as whatever view controller this is in is visible and loaded. This way you can have a method that resizes the same drawn rect. You would simply call this whenever you need to resize it.

```
-(void)resizeRect {
     transformingRect = CGRectUnion(view1.frame, view2.frame);
}
```

Comment: In drawRect, when I draw a rectangle, I need to create an object of that rectangle, not of the frame. I need to know how to delete the previous rectangle. Please read the question properly.

Comment: CGRect is a value, not an object. There's no need to declare it as `CGRect *`